# Field of type "string". Query returns no results even if query string is stored in such a field

Tags: solr

I am debugging a search problem in an application involving Solr-Search.
We have a field named "author" there, defined in schema.xml. 
We see documents with a value in it, so this field gets indexed properly as it seems.
But we do not get any results when we search for some content in such a field.

The original field definition is this:

```
<field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" />
```

If there is an indexed value like "Mad Max", there are no result for neither "Mad", "Max" nor "Mad Max".
But when there is a value like "MadMax", there will be a result if we search for "MadMax" exactly. Neither "madmax" nor anything else works.

Now I read in the docs for Solr 6 the following for the built in type "StrField" (is it the correct type for "string"?).

> Strings are intended for small fields and are not tokenized or
>   analyzed in any way.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-types-included-with-solr.html

Does it mean, that type="string" is only for single word strings (see "not tokenized") which have to match exactly (see "not analyzed in any way")?

Or is there some other setting where the behaviour for fields of type "string" can be controlled in such a way that partial and case insensitive matches of a multiword content can be reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it mean, that type="string" is only for single word strings (see "not tokenized") which have to match exactly (see "not analyzed in any way")?
     *Yes*

Or is there some other setting where the behaviour for fields of type "string" can be controlled in such a way that partial and case insensitive matches of a multiword content can be reached? 
    *No*

If you have field type of string, the field won't be analysed. There won't be any tokenization of the string even though the string consists of multiple words.

If you want to achieve the search for exact word then you should go for the string type.

If you want to achieve exact search along with in case sensitive then create your own field with `KeywordTokenizerFactory` and `LowerCaseFilterFactory` factory.

```
<fieldType name="text_phrase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If you want to achieve exact search and wild card search like single word search then you can use `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` and combinations of `LowerCaseFilterFactory` and `StopFilterFactory` etc.

```
<fieldType name="text_custom" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

So `KeywordTokenizerFactory` will have a token like `"web world"` as single token in the index.

`WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` will create tokens like `"web ", "world"`.

You can see the difference, it wont match. You are searching for `"web", "world"` against `"web world"`.

Once you have created your own field type, you can verify the same in solr admin page. What all token are created and if it matches any.

You can even control the analysis of index type and query type by having different tokenizer and filters.

Comment: Thx for clarification! Works with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory and LowerCaseFilterFactory.